# How can I hide the "Universal Access" icon in the upper panel?

Tags: icons, panel

If I use Gnome Tweaks to increase the text size, which I find necessary for readability on a 1920x1080 14-inch display, the "Universal Access" icon automatically appears in the upper panel. I do not need this icon/menu and would like to hide or disable it.

Opening "Universal Access" from the Settings app and enabling/disabling the top item "Always Show Universal Access Menu" does not fix my issue.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Accepted answer in duplicate does not work in 19.10. The extension is not anymore updated, and therefore not anymore included in the repositories, although it probably still works fine as appears from the comments on the extension's website.

Comment: I am using 19.10

Comment: This information should be included in the question. The accepted answer does not work because the extension is not anymore included in the Ubuntu PPA. That is because it is not being updated. However, it still works, so the second answer in the duplicate can help you.